# Convert from fr-CA time to US time format

Tags: c#, datetime, string-to-datetime

I have a string datetime like this in fr-CA time : "16 août 1980".

How can i change this string to US time like "16 aug 1980" or "august 16 1980" using c#?

I need create a cultureinfo of this time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to specifiy the cultureInfo.  In this case, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` like so :

```
var myDate = "16 août 1980";
var dateConverted = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "D", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CA"));
var dateUs = dateConverted.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Yeah, i missed that last part.

Comment: To obtain "16 aug 1980" you must change "D" to "d MMM yyyy". With "D" the result is: Saturday, August 16, 1980

Comment: With "MMM d yyyy" you obtain: Aug 16 1980

Comment: That pretty much the format I have used in my answer.